# Bind custom object List to Combox (DisplayMember is not working)

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to bind a List to a Combobox as datasource. My list is composed of custom class objects.
Binding works fine, but I can not set DisplayMember.

My class definitions; I have a custom class "Sett_Colection" that keep a List of another custom class 
"Sett".

```
public class Sett
{
    public string nameOfSett;
    public Sett(){
        ...
    }
}

public class Sett_Colection
{
    public List<Sett> listOfSetts;
    public Sett_Colection(){
        ...
    }
}
```

The code in my Form is something like this;

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    Sett_Colection collectionOfSetts;

    public Form1()
    {
        // Here I add Sett instances into collectionOfSetts
        // So collectionOfSetts.listOfSetts is not empty

        combobox1.DataSource = collectionOfSetts.listOfSetts;
        cmb_ayar.DisplayMember = "nameOfSett";
    }
}
```

When I did this, datasource assigned succesfully. But display member has not been set as "nameOfSett".
The item names display as "Namespace.Sett";

I found a lot of example codes on internet, but none of them worked. I think my situation is a bit different

Comment: What behavior are you actually seeing?  We don't know what isn't working here.  Have you confirmed that listOfSetts is non-Empty?

Comment: thank you @cdkMoose. listOfSetts is not empty. LarsTech's suggestion did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need it to be a property:

```
public string nameOfSett {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case properties were "internal" I changed them to "public" then the problem is solved.